# Best and fastest way for multipling a vector to a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a vector `v` and a matrix `m`. I would like to get the following result in R. How can I do it ?

```
     v = c(1, 2)
     m = matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.3, 2, 5.5), nrow = 5)
     result = matrix(c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 7, 8.6, 4, 11), nrow = 5)
     > result
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1  5.0
    [2,]    0  7.0
    [3,]    1  8.6
    [4,]    1  4.0
    [5,]    0 11.0
```

Comment: Someone could maybe add the Rcpp alternative to the list of benchmarks in that answer. It ought to win, I guess...something like `Rcpp:::cppFunction(
    "arma::mat sweep_mcolvec(arma::mat A, arma::colvec x) 
    { 
        A.each_col() *= x;
        return A;
    }", depends = "RcppArmadillo"
)`. My laptop hasn't been taking benchmarking very well lately, so it won't be me.

Comment: Hi @Frank, I tried your Rcpp code and got `error: no match for 'operator*=' in 'arma::Mat<eT>::each_col() [with eT = double]() *= x` I'm not an Rcpp guru so that's as far as I got.

Answer (score 0):

`*` does element wise multiplies, but you need to do it by column...

```
t( t(m) * v)
```

or use matrix multiply...

```
m %*% diag(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make `v` into a matrix the same size as `m`, and then just multiply.

```
> v[col(m)]*m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1  5.0
[2,]    0  7.0
[3,]    1  8.6
[4,]    1  4.0
[5,]    0 11.0
```